# Error al agregar boton desde codigo puro en JAVA

Tags: java, jbutton

Estoy tratando de agregar un botón dinámico desde el código sin usar la herramienta gráfica de netbeans, pero al momento de correr la interfaz no aparece el botón.

Quisiera saber que me hace falta, este es mi código:

```
private void InitButtonNext(){
    vet = new JButton("A JUGAR!!!");
    vet.setForeground(new Color(0,0,0));
    vet.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenes/icono64.png")));
    vet.setText("A JUGAR!!!");
    vet.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    vet.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    vet.setPressedIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenes/icono64.png"))); 
    vet.setRolloverIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenes/icono76.png"))); 
    vet.setVerticalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
    
    img.add(vet); //Aqui deberia agregar el boton abajo de mi area de texto (Imagen)
```

[image: Se supone que se deberia agregar el boton debajo de mi area de texto]

Comment: Depende del layout que estés usando, pero a lo mejor te falta setearle una posición/tamaño

Comment: ¿A donde lo estas agregando, a una img? Creo que **add**(**Component** comp) se usa solo en objetos tipo **Container** como **JPanel** o **JFrame** ¿Podrías proporcionar mas codigo acerca de todo el proyecto para conocerlo un poco mas?